# Error while creating Proxy Class of GetVehAvailRQ.wsdl Sabre Car Soap API

Tags: c#, api, soap, sabre

getting error while creating proxy class using **wsdl.exe**

```
G:\GetVehAvailRQ_v1.0.0_sample_payloads>wsdl /l:CS /out:CarServce.cs /n:AddCarService GetVehAvailRQ.wsdl

Microsoft (R) Web Services Description Language Utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Error: Unable to import binding 'GetVehAvailRQSoapBinding' from namespace 'https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc'.
  - Unable to import operation 'GetVehAvailRQ'.
  - The element 'http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v02_02:SabreHeader' is missing.

If you would like more help, please type "wsdl /?".
```

Link of Soap API Files that i use in wsdl
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/ground_transportation/search/car_availability/resources

please help me to create a proxy class or suggest me a other way

Comment: The best way of solving issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and look at the request.  The request should look like the one on your link (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/tpfc/OTA_VehAvailRateLLS2.4.2RQ.wsdl).  You need to generate an xml SOAP message.

Comment: hi @jdweng i check wsdl file there is missing xml declaration after i add this problem is still same. i use https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/ website to test wsdl and its required xsd files but i get same error like before(The WSDL document contains additional characters that do not belong into the document. Maybe the WSDL is copied from the Web Browser (probably IE). Try to save the document using the browsers "Save..." function and upload again.)
please open a zip file from above question link there is wsdl file if you check the file problem and help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: i will be very thankfull for you

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: I don't remember, I think it's a Missing Files Problem. check dependencies xsd files.